# How far do I need to travel for the 4 blue distance puzzles?

Tags: blackbox

Near the bottom-right of Blackbox, there are four blue boxes which open a distance-based puzzle. Each part of this puzzle is solved by traveling a certain distance away from home in the real world.

I unlocked the first tier while I was 3 miles from home and the second tier while 40 miles away. However, even after traveling to a different state, the third and fourth tiers remain uncompleted.

How far do I need to travel to solve these distance puzzles?

[image: Blue distance puzzle]

Comment: I just want to add that altitude has an influence on this puzzle as well.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I thought altitude influenced the three light-blue puzzles near the top?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. Only the final ring is based on altitude [as stated here](http://indieobscura.com/article/1108/solutions-to-all-the-blackbox-puzzles).

"Travel far enough to fill the first 3 rings.
Travel to a high enough altitude to fill the last ring."

Although, I can't seem to find _how_ far and _how_ high. I'll add a solution if I can find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to find some concrete numbers, however I would also take into consideration lack of GPS accuracy when performing the puzzle, so the numbers may be slightly off.

Anyways, [Game Solver](https://game-solver.com/blackbox-think-outside-the-box-solutions/blackbox-level-31-34-four-blue-boxes-solutions/) states that this puzzle can be solved by:

> Level 31 -Walk or drive 0.63 Miles to light up the bottom box.
>
> Level 32 -Walk or drive 6.3 Miles to light up the second box.
>
> Level 33 -Walk or drive 63 Miles to light up the third box.
>
> Level 34 -Walk or drive 630 Miles to light up the fourth box.

However, [Indie Obscura](http://indieobscura.com/article/1108/solutions-to-all-the-blackbox-puzzles) states that:

> Travel far enough to fill the first 3 rings.
>
> Travel to a high enough altitude to fill the last ring.

So, overall it sounds like the first three numbers are trustworthy gauges. The last one is most likely based off of some altitude or the distance stated.

Answer (score -2):

The first box is 1 km
The second box is 10 km
The third box is 100 km
The fourth box is 1000 km and has nothing to do with altitude. Its easier to go 1000km by plane than it is any other way so some users have assumed its altitude 'cause their 4th box lit up when they were on a plane but its actually 'cause they had travelled the 1000km

Comment: Where did you get this information from?